# Update database after duration (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, auto-update, duration

I have a cycle model with two fields: duration (string) and completed (boolean).  When a user creates a cycle, they enter the duration (lets say 30 minutes) and the cycle is set to not complete (boolean 0). How do I update that database entry after the cycle duration (30 minutes) to mark the cycle as complete (boolean 1)?  Is there a way to handle this with ruby/rails code, or do I have to execute a javascript function?

The goal is to be able to find and display all completed cycles using Cycle.all(:conditions..) and call the SQL database.  I wrote a "complete?" method in the cycle model that compares the age of the cycle to the duration, but this is useless for SQL find methods.

What's the best way to tackle this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a rake task that runs something like…

```
desc "Expire old cycles"
task :cron => :environment do
  expired = Cycle.all :conditions => ["expiration < ?", DateTime.now]
  expired.each { |c| c.expire! }
end
```

Where `c#expire!` is a method that'll mark it as expired in the database. Then setup `rake cron` to run every N minutes via a cronjob.

If you're comfortable doing this in SQL, you can optimize this by writing a query to do `UPDATE cycles SET complete = 1 WHERE expiration < NOW();`.

Comment: Any way I could do accomplish this without a cron job?  This will be used in a factory environment where the status of the cycle is important such that it should be accurate up to the minute, which would require a cron job to be run every minute.  On shared servers, I've read that this is not good.

Comment: You can attach the much more performant raw SQL query to every request that is made, so it'll be run automatically as the application is used. You can't tell the database to do this automatically on a schedule, though, if that's what you're aiming for.

Comment: Depending on how you intend to interact with this data, indexing the expiration column in the database and using a time comparison condition to only pull out the rows that are unexpired lazily (right-this-moment) is a very acceptable option as well.

Comment: @aguynamedloren update all records seems slow when the db is bigger because it will run dupplicated records so many  time

Answer (score 0):

You can add another field, let's say `Expired_time` that is when the cycle is complete. For example:

```
# Here is the example record:
Duration  Created_at  Expired_time
30 mins   Time        Time + 30 mins
```

And now simply check current date (now) with Expired_time to check it is complete or not.